# Getting a 401 Unauthorized error when calling a modal

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

I'm just trying to call a modal to edit a product, but getting re-directed. Using has_secure_password.. don't have any filters.. I did change the keys in the models..

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :merchant, :foreign_key => 'merchant_identifier', 
  :primary_key => 'merchant_identifier'  
end
```

and my merchant model.. this is my user.. nothing else in this but some validations..

```
class Merchant < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'merchant_identifier'
  has_many :products, :foreign_key => 'merchant_identifier', 
  :primary_key => 'merchant_identifier'
end
```

This is the link_to that calls the modal

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
      <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_product_path(product), remote: true, 
      class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %></td>
  </tr>
```

This is Products#edit

```
def edit
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

I am trying to debug this as well but the code just bounces off my edit action and goes straight to this error. Any idea how I can better debug this?

```
Processing by ProductsController#edit as JS
Parameters: {"id"=>"70"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms
```

Comment: Can you post last request from your server log?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.. it was an around filter, but it was in the gem I was using.. so it was a bit hidden..